# easy but hard probability task

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I have $30$ cards, and $4$ red cards among them. I have $3$ players, each player gets $10$ cards. what is the probability of:

$A$ = player1 gets all $4$ red cards

$B$ = each player gets $1$ card.

I am stuck not knowing how to calculate the probability of $A$ and $B$.

I tried to solve in this way: I have $30$ cards, each player gets $10$ cards. the probability of getting $1$ red card for each player is $1/3$. am I right? I cannot go further... please help

Comment: You could help people to help you by indicating what you tried to solve this problem and which similar problems you can solve. Otherwise it looks as if you were using MSE to get freely your homework done for you.

Comment: @Did, yeah, sorry. I added my attempt, please see my question

Comment: "I have 30 cards, each player gets 10 cards. the probability of getting 1 red card for each player is 1/3"... I am not sure that this qualifies as "showing what you tried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n(A)=4C_4*26C_6*20C_{10}*10C_{10}\\n(S)=30C_{10}*20C_{10}*10C_{10 } $$ where $n(S),n(A)$ denote the the no of element  in sample space and event space of $A$ respectively.

Similarly you can find $n(B)$. Please try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A: Give $4$ red cards to p1. Then out of remaining $26$ cards, give $6$ to p1, $10$ to p2 and $10$ to p3. The total possibilities = distributing $30$ cards equally among p1, p2 and p3.

B: I think there is a typing mistake. Also since there are $4$ red cards $(1,1,1)$ isn't feasible.

Comment: thanks, but B definition is right regarding 4 cards. this is the point why the task gets hard.

Comment: Well the question says each player gets 10 cards each out of 4 red and 26 non-red. Since 4 red cards will be distributed, how can each player get only 1 red card. Where will the last red card go??

Answer (score 1):

For the Part B, agreed to Uma kant said, probability is ZERO if the question is correct. It is impossible.

However, if the Part B is like what I said below, then it is another story.

B = each player gets **at least** 1 card.

So May I confirm if the question is what I said?

Comment: yeah, please continue

Answer (score 1):

Then I would say the answer is like this,

```
Player 1 = P1, Player 2 = P2, Player 3 = P3, R = no of Red Card

        R    R    R
P1      1    1    2     
P2      1    2    1
P3      2    1    1

= total 3 cases 

Combination for P1, P2, P3 at least 1 card
= 3 * (1 Red Card + 9 non red card )* (1 Red Card + 9 non red card )* (2 Red Card + 8 non red card - remain and need not to concern)
= 3 * 4C1 * 26C9 * 4C1 * 26C9 
= 562981419000

Total combination 
= 30C10 * 20C10 * 10C10
= 5550996791340
```

**>     P(P1, P2, P3 at least 1 Red card)
= 0.101**